# Supress VB msgbox whilst a macro runs

Tags: excel, vba

I've inherited an Excel tool that has a bug I want to fix. Some sheets are hidden using code to prevent users tampering with them, they're hidden using the below code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Application.UserName = "Smith, John" Then
    Exit Sub
Else 
    MsgBox "You do not have permission to view this"
    Worksheets("General").Activate
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Within another module there is code that runs a simple function based upon the values within these hidden sheets. So whenever a user without permission runs the code they are presented with the MsgBox saying "You do not have permission to view this" - if they press 'OK' the code runs successfully but it isn't efficient.

How can I suppress the MsgBox whilst this code is running, then activate it once it's completed?

I'm OK with VBA but certain things go over my head so any help would be great!

The calling code is:

```
If Not check_setup_input Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Worksheets("lists").Cells(2, 16).Value2 = True

show_user_who_completes_form

row_control.hide_relevant_rows

With Worksheets("General").Cells(12, 4)
    .Value2 = "Calculate"
    .Interior.Color = 49407
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
End With
```

Comment: A boolean set to false, if the msgbox should trigger flip it to true, if true then msgbox at the end.

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts=False`

Comment: @Warcupine I've tried doing this but am struggling to embed the Boolean into the code. The code that hides the sheets and the code that executes the function are in different modules - so I'm not sure this would be possible.

Comment: @cyboashu I should have mentioned that I tried to use DisplayAlerts within the calling code but this didn't work

Comment: @Turner - it's likely possible. Sharing the code in the other module might be helpful.

Comment: @BigBen Cheers - I've added the code to the bottom of the module. Essentially that code calls some subs that validate the user has completed the form correctly. Then it calls another module and runs a sub from there. There's a lot going on - which makes just suppressing some message boxes really frustrating

Comment: If the code wasn't activating the hidden sheets, you wouldn't have this problem. Code that activates sheets can always be re-written to not use the active sheet, and is better for the re-write.

Answer (score 0):

Warcupine's idea is best. "[Create] a boolean set to false, if the msgbox should trigger flip it to true, if true then msgbox at the end."

To resolve your issue of having the executing and triggered code in seperate modules, create a [Module-Level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#module-level) Public Boolean type variable. because it is module level, it retains its value after execution has ended as long as the application has not closed or been reset. Because it is public, it will be accessible by other modules.

To create a Module-Level variable, place it at the top of the module, outside of any code block. To make it public use the `Public` keyword instead of `Dim`.

```
Public sendMsgBox as Boolean
'Put this at the top of the module
```

Remember to reset it back to default value for each new execution of your code. Otherwise it might be set to true once, and then stay true for each subsequent execution.

Comment: Alternatively you could pass the boolean variable to the procedure by reference.